# Having trouble getting webpage format nicely to different monitor sizes

Tags: html, css

I am having trouble getting my website to adapt to different monitor screen sizes. I am doing an image gallery with six pictures and captions. On my laptop, the webpage displays nicely and when I go to a bigger monitor with the same browser, the image gallery format is off. I will post a few pictures and my code to show what is going on.

What happens to site on larger monitors, unformatted  sizing:

[image: What happens to site on larger monitors, unformatted sizing]

```css
/* controls background of the gallery */
.black {
 position: relative;
 width: 100%;
 height: 1150px;
 background-color: black;
 margin: auto;
 padding: 10px; 
 border: 1px solid black;

}


/* text for title of the gallery */
.galleryTitle{
 
 text-align: center;
 position: relative;
 color: white;
 font-size: 50px;
 font-weight: bold;
 
}


/* inserts image below title */
.five img {
 
 position: relative;
 width: 400px;
 height: 150px;
 left: 650px; 
 bottom: 60px;
}


/* code for gallery*/

/* makes border and box around images*/
div.gallery {
    margin-left: 110px;
    border: 2px solid #ccc;
    float: left;
    width: 15px;
    height: 5px; 
 position: relative;
}

/* controls the image width and heights */

div.gallery img {
    width: 100%;
    height: 250px;
}

/* controls the caption formatting */ 

div.desc {
    padding: 5%;
    text-align: center;
 color: red;
 font-size: 25px;
}

h1, h2 {
  display: inline;
  background: #fff;

}

/* format screen size for different devices */

@media only screen and (max-width : 480px) {
   /* Smartphone view: 1 tile */
   div.gallery {
      width: 100%;
      padding-bottom: 100%;
   }
}

@media only screen and (max-width : 650px) and (min-width : 481px) {
   /* Tablet view: 2 tiles */
   div.gallery {
      width: 50%;
      padding-bottom: 50%;
   }
}
@media only screen and (max-width : 1050px) and (min-width : 651px) {
   /* Small desktop / ipad view: 3 tiles */
   div.gallery {
      width: 33.3%;
      padding-bottom: 33.3%;
   }
}
@media only screen and (max-width : 2560px) and (min-width : 1051px) {
   /* Medium desktop: 4 tiles */
   div.gallery {
      width: 25%;
      padding-bottom: 25%;
   }
}
```

```html
<div class = "black">

<p class = "galleryTitle">Galleries</p><br>

<div class = "five">
 <img src = "pinklines.png">
</div>

<!-->start of gallery </!-->

<div class="gallery">

  <a target="_blank" href="gallery1.html">
    <img src="imagesGalery1/33.jpg" alt="Fjords" width="300" height="100">
  </a>
  <div class="desc">CyberGirlz colorcoded Fall 2015 </div>
</div>

<div class="gallery">
  <a target="_blank" href="gallery2.html">
    <img src="imagesGalery1/1.jpg" alt="Forest" width="300" height="100">
  </a>
  <div class="desc">CyberGirlz colorcoded Spring 2016 </div>
</div>

<div class="gallery">
  <a target="_blank" href="gallery3.html">
    <img src="imagesGalery1/8.jpg" alt="Northern Lights" width="300" height="100">
  </a>
  <div class="desc">Wright Bendyworks visits UWW May 2017 </div>
</div>

<div class="gallery">
  <a target="_blank" href="gallery4.html">
    <img src="imagesGalery1/26.jpg" alt="Mountains" width="300" height="100">
  </a>
  <div class="desc">Visiting Wright Bendyworks April 2017 </div>
</div>

<div class="gallery">
  <a target="_blank" href="gallery5.html">
    <img src="imagesGalery1/27.jpg" alt="Northern Lights" width="300" height="100">
  </a>
  <div class="desc">Teen Tech Thursdays Fall 2017 </div>
</div>

<div class="gallery">
  <a target="_blank" href="gallery6.html">
    <img src="imagesGalery1/31.jpg" alt="Mountains" width="300" height="100">
  </a>
  <div class="desc">Web Design Young Athletes March 2017 </div>
  
</div>
</div>
```

Comment: Where is the problem? In black background which ends earlier than the content? Or...?

Comment: In the black background that ends earlier. it only does this on larger monitors and not on my laptop screen. Not sure why this is and want this is the problem I have been facing.

Comment: Remove `height: 100%` from `.black` and add there `overflow: hidden`

Comment: That worked, thank you very much,how do I make my page more adaptive when I shrink the page to maintain formatting.